# Why can't we log in with multiple accounts in same browser? (GMail)

Tags: session

Is that possible, or not even with tabbed browsing? Why?

Comment: Yes, why dont we cant???

Comment: In my mind the real question is "why don't you can?"

Comment: I have would surely tried to can help you if I should have can knowed why dont' we should cant open a tabbed browsing can of beans.

Answer (score 3):

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/access-two-gmail-accounts-at-once-in.html

> Now, you can visit google.com/accounts and click the link next to "Multiple sign-in." After you sign into your first account, you can sign in with up to two additional accounts from the new accounts menu in the upper right hand corner of Gmail, then easily toggle back and forth between them. You can even open multiple Gmail tabs — one for each of your accounts.